# How to import firstValueFrom function from rxjs in Angular 13?

Tags: angular, rxjs, frontend, mean-stack, rxjs5

Module '"rxjs"' has no exported member 'firstValueFrom'.ts(2305)

[image: Getting error Module '"rxjs"' has no exported member 'firstvalueFrom' .ts(2305)]

Comment: check your version of rxjs in node modules as its only available after rxjs 7.x

Comment: Angular 13 by default uses RxJS 6.5. `firstValueFrom` is available since RxJS 7.0

Answer (score 1):

Check your version of rxjs in node modules as firstValueFrom is only available after rxjs 7.x